# Как сохранить конфиги настройки L2TP в open Suse11.3 ?

Tags: suse, gnome, l2tp, xl2tp

Хочу начисто переустановить систему и перейти на 11.4, и в связи с этим возник вопрос: как мне сохранить настройки сети, а у меня сеть "Киевстар домашний интернет", работающий по протоколу L2TP и помня, как я возился с настройкой - хотелось бы просто взять скопировать конфиги все на флешке, а потом установив  xl2tp, просто взять и закинуть эти конфиги. И вообще хочу перейти на Gnome 3.2 (сейчас у меня KDE 4.4.4) как мне безболезненно вообще перейти? Как лучше сделать, с наименьшими движениями, тем более, что сейчас рабочее все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте утилиту tar.

```
tar -cf <имя_архива.tar> <каталог/с/конфигами>
```

После этого скопируйте архив на флешку и восстановите в уже новой системе так:

```
tar -xpf <имя_архива.tar> -C /тот/же/каталог/откуда/брали/конфиги
```

-c - создать новый архив

-f - работать с файлом, а не с накопителем на магнитной ленте

-x - распаковать архив

-p - восстановить привилегии на распакованные элементы

-С - перейти в каталог, куда нужно распаковать после открытия архива, но перед добавлением файлов.

Для более полного разъяснения уточните, как Вы настраивали сеть.